# How to handle packages shadowing each other?

Tags: python, ubuntu, package, shadowing

I've installed most of my modules through Ubuntu packages, and consequently they're in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.  Some are too old or not available through Ubuntu, so I've installed them through pip, and they're in `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages`.

So far so good.  However, *both* contain a package `mpl_toolkits`, but with different contents.  `import mpl_toolkits.basemap` fails despite the presence of `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap`, because `mpl_toolkits` is found first in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits`, which contains a number of modules, but not `basemap`.

So, in effect, the distribution-level `mpl_toolkits` is shadowing custom-installed `mpl_toolkits`.  What is a correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this should be taken care of by the packages `__path__` attribute:

```
In [4]: mpl_toolkits.__path__ 
Out[4]: 
['/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits']
```

However, *if the second `mpl_toolkits` is installed* ***after*** *the first one was imported*, it needs to be reloaded for `mpl_toolkits` to realise its distribution over multiple locations on the file system.